# PHP: Header not working properly

Tags: php

I have a secure webpage which only allow access to a certain IP address in PHP but I also added a referer condition too, in case I have to access outside of my intranet to make edits. For some reason it's not working.

Heres my **EDITED** redirect page name in2.php (working):

```
<?php
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.mysite.com/in.php"></HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here's my in.php code:

```
    <?php
    $visitor = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $referer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
    if (preg_match("/152.12.32.65/", $visitor) || $referer == "http://www.mysite.com/in2.php") {
    << MY SITE >>
    }
    else {
    echo "not accessible";
    }
    ?>
}
```

When i access in2.php from a mobile phone and even though the IP address is different shouldn't it still allow me to view the site? I only get the "not accessible" text. Is it because I am using a "header()" function in in2.php?
If I change it to let's say an HTML/Jquery redirect, would it work?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: What's the value of $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]?

Comment: neither ip or referer are a safe way to restrict access. referer is browser set, and ip is spoffable

Comment: From the php.net docs: **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] - The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.**...this is not a reliable variable to check.

Comment: you can use session instead , set session in in2.php , then redirect it to in.php, and check session is set or not

Comment: @Siamak.A.M , war10ck answer the question , `Not all user agents will set this` , good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header function sets the one location header. You might need to add the referrer header by yourself as you do not tell the browser, that it just hit a redirect. The better option might be sending a correct 301 or 307. I'm on my phone at the moment so the links and references are missing due laziness ;).

Comment: I accepted your answer. If it's possible when you get a chance, if you can elaborate on the 301 or 307 :)